# Put field value in validation annotation

Tags: java, bean-validation

```
public class Person {

    private String id;

    @Min(value = 1, message = "Age of person id '${id}' must be greater than 0.")
    private int age;
}
```

Is it possible to make `'${id}'` take the value of the id field in this class?

Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneS: I don't think it's a duplicate. I cannot use a `@ScriptAssert` in my case. I just want to display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. I have asked a similar question. The problem is that annotations can't deal with variables. Only a final variable can be passed to annotation.